# Entity Framework is combining my table name and the Id name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

This is an odd issue.  My Entity Framework Core project is combining the table and the Id into one column like this:   MonsterListMonsterId

Here is the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'MonsterListMonsterId'
```

This is the controller that generates the error:

```
var treasuresByMonster = await _context.MonsterTreasures.Where(q => q.MonsterId == id).ToListAsync();
```

Clearly the column is called MonsterId.  Not MonsterListMonsterId.

Here is the MonsterList class:

```
public class MonsterList
{
    public MonsterList()
    {
        MonsterTreasures = new HashSet<MonsterTreasures>();
    }
    public Guid MonsterId { get; set; }
    public string MonsterText { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MonsterTreasures> MonsterTreasures { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the MonsterTreasure class:

```
public partial class MonsterTreasures
{
    public Guid TreasureId { get; set; }
    public Guid? MonsterId { get; set; }
    public string TreasureText { get; set; }
    public MonsterList MonsterList { get; set; }

}
```

And the context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MonsterTreasures>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.TreasureId);
    
    entity.HasOne(e => e.MonsterList)
        .WithMany(m => m.MonsterTreasures);
        
    entity.ToTable("MonsterTreasures");

    entity.Property(e => e.TreasureId)
        .HasColumnName("TreasureId");

    entity.Property(e => e.MonsterId)
        .HasColumnName("MonsterId");

    entity.Property(e => e.TreasureText)
        .HasColumnName("TreasureText");

});
```

What is a proper fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: This error usually indicates improper (or conventional) mapping of FK property/column name. In order to tell you the exact problem and how to fix it, we need to see the `MonsterTreasure` class and fluent config if any.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks Ivan, I added a bunch of code.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here

```
public Guid? MonsterId { get; set; }
public MonsterList MonsterList { get; set; }
```

The name 'MonsterId` does not match any of the EF Core [conventional FK property names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#fully-defined-relationships):

> - `<navigation property name><principal key property name>`
> - `<navigation property name>Id`
> - `<principal entity name><principal key property name>`
> - `<principal entity name>Id`

Because of that EF Core does not consider it as a FK property and assumes shadow property / column with default name from the exception message.

In order to fix the issue you have to map it explicitly by either `[ForeignKey]` data annotation on FK property specifying the navigation property name:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(MonsterList)]
public Guid? MonsterId { get; set; }
public MonsterList MonsterList { get; set; }
```

or on navigation property specifying the name of the FK property:

```
public Guid? MonsterId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(MonsterId)]
public MonsterList MonsterList { get; set; }
```

or with `HasForeignKey` Fluent API here:

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.MonsterList)
    .WithMany(m => m.MonsterTreasures)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MonsterId); // <--
```

Comment: is it because it's a type of Guid?

Comment: As already mentioned,  the problem is **name**, not type.

Comment: Since the PK type is Guid, both Guid (required) and Guid? (optional) are valid FK property types.  Take a look at the whole [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) documentation topic, everything is explained there.

Comment: Thanks I was using the Microsoft Docs and they used BlogId and PostId so I thought MonsterId would be fine.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Yes, but they match `<navigation property name>Id` pattern - `<Blog>Id` and `<Post>Id`, while your doesn't  -  the navigation property name in your case is `MonsterList`, so it would match name `MonsterListId`.